# How i can handle garbage?

Tags: c

I am novice to C. I am trying to write a program to calculate the Hypotenuse, but when I run it I get garbage values and I don't know how to handle it.

```
double Hypotenuse(double base, double perpendicular)
{
  double hyp = sqrt((base*base) + (perpendicular*perpendicular));

  return hyp;
}

int _tmain(void)
{
  double b, p;

  printf("Enter the lenght of base\n");
  scanf_s("%f",&b);

  printf("Enter the lenght of perpendicular\n");
  scanf_s("%f",&p);

  printf("The hypotenuse of the triangle is %3.3f",Hypotenuse(b,p));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `"%lf"` for `double`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why so? Ah you mean in the scanf? I was looking at the printf.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan read reference. also It may be used for printf.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY read what reference? %f is fine for double in printf.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I recommend that the reference of scanf also read (for you).

Comment: who can not see the reference is too much!

Comment: Also put a space at the beginning of your scanf format string so it ignores whitespace. (Like the newline)

Comment: @dvnrrs Not necessary because it is the default behavior it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Never mind. I know how scanf works.

Comment: read once again both.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY No it isn't... are you intentionally trolling? You're not helping here.

Comment: @dvnrrs I do not know the your say's meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is in your scanf statements.
As a thumb rule you should always use "%lf" for doubles.
This works perfectly:

```
double Hypotenuse(double base, double perpendicular)
{
  double hyp = sqrt((base*base) + (perpendicular*perpendicular));

  return hyp;
}

int _tmain(void)
{
  double b, p;

  printf("Enter the lenght of base\n");
  scanf_s("%lf",&b);

  printf("Enter the lenght of perpendicular\n");
  scanf_s("%lf",&p);

  printf("The hypotenuse of the triangle is %3.3lf",Hypotenuse(b,p));

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the best way to see what is going on in your code or where u get garbage, after all scanf print the value
ex:

```
double a;
scanf("%f",&a);
printf("a=%f",a); //OR
printf("a=%3.3f",a);
```

and you can easy see if the problem is in your scanf or somewhere else..

Comment: And why no real debugger?

Comment: @deviantfan the problem is not the real debugger, i was helping him to  uderstand how the debugger works.. or i dont know.. when i stop somewhere or i have problem i always debug by my self.. thats works good for me